# Quantidade em um dataset

Tags: python

Possuo este dataset
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de contar as instancias de 'DATA_CRIA' com relação a este outro dataset
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para isso realizei este comando, só que não funcionou:

`lista = []
    for ano in anos:
        lista.append(oni['DATA_CRIA'].count()
        print(lista)`

Comment: Por favor, faça o [tour] e leia o guia de [ask]. Não está exatamente claro o que desejas fazer e busque evitar postar códigos como imagem. Muitos usuários não conseguem ver imagens, piora a experiência de navegação pelo aplicativo móvel e prejudica a busca do site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumi que você está usando Pandas e DataFrame.

Partindo disso:

```
import pandas as pd

anos = [2008, 2009, 2010]

d = {'DISTANCIA': [12.3, 33.3, 11.1, 43.4], 'DATA_CRIA': [2008, 2008, 2009, 1909]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> print df
   DATA_CRIA  DISTANCIA
0       2008       12.3
1       2008       33.3
2       2009       11.1
3       1909       43.4
```

Podemos criar uma função que conta a ocorrência de um ano dado um dataframe:

```
def conta_ocorrencias(df, ano):
    ocorrencias = 0
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.iloc[i]['DATA_CRIA'] == ano:
            ocorrencias += 1
    return ocorrencias
```

E ai fazemos:

```
lista = []
for ano in anos:
    lista.append(conta_ocorrencias(df, ano))
>>> print lista
[2, 1, 0]
```

Porem esse jeito não é muito eficiente, porque percorre o df uma vez para cada ano, então podemos mudar a abordagem.

```
#crio um dicionario com os anos como chave para contar as ocorrencias
dic_ano = {}
for ano in anos:
    dic_ano.update({ano:0})
>>> print dic_ano
{2008: 0, 2009: 0, 2010: 0}
```

E ai percorro o df apenas uma vez assim:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for ano in anos:
        if df.iloc[i]['DATA_CRIA'] == ano:
            dic_ano[ano] = dic_ano[ano]+1
>>> print dic_ano
{2008: 2, 2009: 1, 2010: 0}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mais o problema é que preciso do resultado do ano mais a somatória dos anos anteriores, e quero o resultado em uma lista.

Comment: Fiz um exemplo manualmente: `listas=[]
oni_8=gd.loc[gd['DATA_CRIA'] <= 2008]
depois8= oni_8['FROTA'].sum()
listas.append(depois8)` , o que eu quero é varrer o dataset com isso, para criar uma lista com as quantidades de cada ano.

Comment: A coluna 'FROTA' possui somente números inteiros